# How to download and emulate the official android x86 image from Android Studio?

Tags: linux, android-emulator, android-x86, emulators

Android studio downloads x86 images from google and emulate them so I can test my apps. I tried downloading and unzipping the thing it downloads but it doesn't look like an image that can be run with virt-manager.

Which images are downloaded by Android Studio and how can I emulate them in Ubuntu?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Are simply looking for a way to Android virtual device via Android studio on linux ? You want to know the files downloaded by Android studio needed  to run the official images?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I want to emulate the images that android studiio downloads. I've managed to download the zip files, but they contain more than a simple ISO image, I don't know how to run

Comment: androidx86? Isnt that a desktop OS? Just run it in a VirtualBox, You'll have to google its setup i cannot remember off the top of my head.

Comment: @DanBrown but I need the official android images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want achieve, this has been documented pretty well on SE sister sites:

Firstly assuming you have successfully installed Android studio, it needs the following files to successfully run an AVD:

- sdk tools
- build tools
- platform tools
- system-images
- sources etc

(*You may download these separately as zipped files, but make sure to extract in the correct directory*)

[image]

In case you haven't got Android studio (or standalone sdk manager) up and running, you may need to get started by following these posts on sister sites:

1. Stackoverflow: [How to install Android SDK on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34556884/7551330)
2. AskUbuntu: [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/318246/653540)

   - Unlike on Windows, you can simply access avd manager using command-line i.e open terminal ( CTRL + ALT + T) and type `android avd` to open the Android Virtual Device Manager.
   - Configure your virtual device to suit your needs, click start and from here you can launch your AVD

Comment: My idea was to run it independently of Android Studio and maybe from SDK. If it's a x86 image, then why I can't simply run on KVM? Is there a way?